# Log in and sign up and notification system on the same page

Tags: python, django

i am developing a website, where people can buy service, also the it has a notification system, i do this in **views** to show log in and sign up, on **index.html**

**Views.py**

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from app.models import *
from app.forms import *
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from ajaxuploader.views import AjaxFileUploader
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.template.defaulttags import csrf_token

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    else:
        form = RegistroUserForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.all()
    return render(request,'app/index.html',context)

def registro_usuario_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Si el method es post, obtenemos los datos del formulario
        form = RegistroUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        # Comprobamos si el formulario es valido
        if form.is_valid():
            # En caso de ser valido, obtenemos los datos del formulario.
            # form.cleaned_data obtiene los datos limpios y los pone en un
            # diccionario con pares clave/valor, donde clave es el nombre del campo
            # del formulario y el valor es el valor si existe.
            cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
            username = cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = cleaned_data.get('password')
            email = cleaned_data.get('email')
            # E instanciamos un objeto User, con el username y password
            user_model = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            # Añadimos el email
            user_model.email = email
            # Y guardamos el objeto, esto guardara los datos en la db.
            user_model.save()
            # Ahora, creamos un objeto UserProfile, aunque no haya incluido
            # una imagen, ya quedara la referencia creada en la db.
            user_profile = UserProfile()
            # Al campo user le asignamos el objeto user_model
            user_profile.user = user_model
            # Por ultimo, guardamos tambien el objeto UserProfile
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        # Si el mthod es GET, instanciamos un objeto RegistroUserForm vacio
        form = RegistroUserForm()
    # Creamos el contexto
    context = {'form': form}
    # Y mostramos los datos
    return render(request, 'app/registro.html', context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from .models import *
from multiupload.fields import MultiFileField
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    images = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=100, max_file_size=1024*1024*5)

class RegistroUserForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(min_length=5,widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_username(self):
        """Comprueba que no exista un username igual en la db"""
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Nombre de usuario ya registrado.')
        return username

    def clean_email(self):
        """Comprueba que no exista un email igual en la db"""
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Este E-mail ya se encuentra registrado.')
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        """Comprueba que password y password2 sean iguales."""
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Las contraseñas no coinciden.')
        return password2
```

**Models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    Usuario = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
    Cargo_Contacto = models.CharField("Cargo del cliente",max_length=50,null=True)
    Celular = models.PositiveIntegerField("Numero de celular",null=True)
    Pagina_web = models.URLField("Pagina Web",blank=True)
    Numero_de_identificacion = models.PositiveIntegerField("Numero de identificacion",null=True)
    Nombre_Empresa = models.CharField("Nombre de la empresa",max_length=50,null=True)
    Telefono = models.PositiveIntegerField("Numero de telefono",null=True)
    Extension_Telefono = models.PositiveIntegerField("Extension del telefono",null=True)
    GeneroEscoger = ((1,"Sin especificar"),(2,'Masculino'),(3,'Femenino'))
    Genero = models.IntegerField(choices=GeneroEscoger, default=1)
    Ciudades = ( (1,'Bogotá'),(2,'Medellin'),(3,'Cali'),(4,'Barranquilla'),(5,'Cartagena'),(6,'Cucuta'),(7,'Ibagué'),(8,'Bucaramanga'),(9,'Otro'))
    Ciudad = models.IntegerField('Ciudad',choices=Ciudades, default=1,)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cliente'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Clientes'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Usuario.username

class Notificaciones(models.Model):
    IDcliente = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    Tipo_de_notificaciones = ( (1,'Ofertas'),(2,'Error'),(3,'Informacion'))
    Tipo = models.IntegerField('Tipo de notificacion',choices=Tipo_de_notificaciones, default=3,)
    Nombre_not = models.CharField("Nombre de la notifiacion",max_length=50)
    Descripcion_not = HTMLField("Descripcion de la notificacion")
    Imagen_not = models.ImageField("Imagen de la notificacion",upload_to="notificaciones")
    Fecha_Caducidad_notificacion = models.DateTimeField("Fecha de caducidad de la notificacion",auto_now_add=False)
    Estado = models.BooleanField("Estado de la notificacion", default=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Notificacion'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Notificaciones'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nombre_not
```

here is 
**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls', namespace='auth')),
    url(r'^social/',include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    #url(r'^s$', 'app.views.CategoriaProductoss', name='servicios'),
    #url(r'^s/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'app.views.servicioscategoria', name='servicioscategoria'),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$','django.views.static.serve', {'document_root':settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.index', name='Vulpini.co'),
    url(r'^login$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='Vulpini.co'),
    url(r'^logout$','django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',{'template_name': 'app/registration/login.html',},name='logout'),
    url(r'start$', 'app.views.start', name="start"),
    url(r'ajax-upload$', 'app.views.import_uploader', name="my_ajax_upload"),
    url(r'^registro$', 'app.views.index', name='registro'),
```

i am thinking about this app, because, am really new on Python and Django, want to know if someone can to make me somes recomendations about it, the idea is something like Godaddy, where people buy services and a notifications system like Youtube or Google notification
my question this is wrong or right?
someone can help me
Thanks so much

Comment: does the code work or does it give you an error?

Comment: @user2719875 now it Works, i can log in, i can't sign up yet, and notifications system just show me all notifications are show but no just a specific user

Comment: What's the question??

Comment: @dietbacon if someone can check if codic is right, because, i am not sure about with the functionality to make the website

Comment: please give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PaulEvans well, i am not sure, i just want if someone can help me with some recomentations with the code i have, beacuse i have my doubts, but i understand, if people can't help, because is a lot of things to analyze

Comment: @Alfredhb.q then perhaps [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for this.

Comment: Assuming your Code currently works (and I get the impression that it does), this would be a great fit for [CodeReview.se]

Comment: @PaulEvans thanks you